# Calculate the percentage internal rate of return

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, irr

Following is the code I am trying to use to get my result, and I am getting an error:

```
import numpy

array = [-1000,0,0,1094.60,0,0,1094.60]

for b in array:
    a = round(numpy.irr(array), b-1) * 100 
print (round(a,2))
```

Error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

But, just replacing that "b-1" makes my code work, but I can't use that because array could be as large or as small as possible. I am not allowed to manually enter numbers replacing that "b-1". Following is the same working code.

```
import numpy

array = [-1000,0,0,1094.60,0,0,1094.60]

for b in array:
    a = round(numpy.irr(array), 6) * 100 
print (round(a,2))
```

I need a way to do it automatically for any size of array.

Answer (score 1):

You got the error because you tried to to round the rate to 1093.60 decimal places (that's b-1 for the 4th iteration).

[**numpy.arr**](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.irr.html) works on any size of array.  You do not have to give it a size (and you didn't).  I gather that you're trying to print the interest rate as a percentage, rounded to 2 decimal places.  Use this instead:

```
rate = numpy.irr(array) * 100
print "rate =", round(rate, 2)
```

Using this at the end of the code I gave you earlier gives this output for comparison:

```
Present Value (P) at rate 0.0125 = 0.217803365612
Present Value (P) at rate 0.01875 = -0.143198101517
Present Value (P) at rate 0.015625 = 0.0349275148787
Present Value (P) at rate 0.0171875 = -0.0547196000329
Present Value (P) at rate 0.01640625 = -0.0100432897584
Present Value (P) at rate 0.016015625 = 0.0124051532756
Present Value (P) at rate 0.0162109375 = 0.00117171042648
rate = 1.62
```

Comment: Okay. That does it. Now, I can just use the same code that I had on my previous post to get everything right ? or no ? Because I am using the same code and i don't get the same value for the "netflow". However, when I did it on paper it is matching with the answer I have.

Comment: Please be clear.  You ask me whether you can use the same code, but then state that the same code doesn't give you the same value.  I can hardly check the original data, since that post seems to be gone, and is under a different account.

Comment: I don't mean the original code. The last code I have on this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35661992/how-do-i-formulate-an-equation-so-that-it-calculates-my-i-value/35662689#35662689       You can answer on there now